# Why doesn't my screen turn off with this automator service?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator

I have created an automator task to run a screen to turn my screens off, using the keyboard shortcuts section in the System Preferences I able to map this to a keyboard shortcut.

My automator script looks like this:
[image]

My keyboard shortcut mapped to the automator service:
[image]

If I press the Run button in the automator, the screens do turn off. However if I press the keyboard shortcut the Mac makes that error nudge noise and nothing happens.

Any ideas why it works in automator but not through the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Do you have your F-keys set the right way? Test with Fn/Cmd/F1

Comment: I've tried setting to it OPT + / and this also doesn't work.